# SmsManager envio de SMS

Tags: android, sms

Estou tentando enviar um SMS com o seguinte código:

```
final SmsManager smsManager = SmsManager.getDefault(); 
    smsManager.sendTextMessage("phone", null, "Message", null, null);
```

Mas não acontece nada, ele executa o código, não ocorre erro e não enviar o SMS. 
Desde já agradeço ! 
Saudações,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consegui enviar da seguinte forma:

```
 smsManager.sendMultipartTextMessage(phone, null ,smsManager.divideMessage(textmessage), null, null);
```

Saudações